# ListAnimate problem

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, animation, style

Imagine I want to use `ListAnimate` on the follow list

```
gl = {Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]], 
   Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, .1}, {1, 0}}]]};
ListAnimate[gl]
```

[image]

Is it possible to fix it so that both lines are in the relative correct positions? I know that by adding another fixed element this kinda solve the issue, for example, take

```
re = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .1}];
glr = {Graphics[{White, re, Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}], 
   Graphics[{White, re, Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, .1}, {1, 0}}]}]};
ListAnimate[glr]
```

[image]

How can make this more autonomous? Maybe adding a constant background?

Comment: add the option `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, .1}}` to both `Graphics[...]`?

Comment: @kglr is there a way of not having to add it to every object in `Graphics`?

Comment: how about `ListAnimate[Show[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, .1}}] & /@ gl]`?

Comment: Or `gl = {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {.5, .1}, {1, 0}}}; SetOptions[Graphics, PlotRange -> {All, {-0.025, 0.125}}]; ListAnimate[Graphics[Line[#]] & /@ gl]` To restore the default option use `SetOptions[Graphics, PlotRange -> All];`